# Creating a dynamic horizontal view with static-width child views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, uistackview

I've spent days trying to get this to work, but nothing seems to be going right.

What I'm trying to do is basically recreate this view (NOT the functionality):

[image]

However, I have a few extra requirements that I've set for myself. When the user moves their finger over one of the emojis, it should do two things:

1. Scale the emoji x2
2. Push the two emojis on either side further out

I don't need help with the above, I just wanted to explain what I want this view to do.

What I need help with is how I should put this view together.

I've tried using a `Stack View`, which I thought would work, but it doesn't seem to work very well with child views that have static widths (I want each emoji to be 32px wide and tall).

Then, after I put the stack view together, I implemented the scale x2 effect, which worked great, but then I had issues trying to push the two emojis on either side further out. I discovered [setCustomSpacing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/2866023-setcustomspacing?language=objc), but this never worked no matter what I tried, and I have a feeling it's because I need my stack view's width to be dynamic (in order to add new emojis and remove old ones at will). The spacing never changed.

So I'm asking how you think I should put this view together? Should I stick with stack view? Why can't I get it to work? Or should I use a different view hierarchy altogether?

Comment: *"I implemented the scale x2 effect"* ... how are you scaling the view?